# Can't get location googleApiClient

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to get the user's location with the GoogleApiClient, it works fine if the GPS is enabled when the activity starts, however, if it is not enabled and i ask for the user to enable the GPS, i can't seem to get the location. I am trying to use a LocationListener, I have tried both the native and the GooglePlayServices listeners. Here is my code:

Check if GPS is enabled in onCreate:

```
    //Ask the user to enable GPS if it is not.
    mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy = new LocationRequest()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(3600000)
            .setFastestInterval(300000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            //final LocationSettingsStates states = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.d("Location error", e.toString());
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

If the result is RESOLUTION REQUIRED, I run the onResult method where I start listening for location if the user accepts to enable GPS:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    // All required changes were successfully made
                    // User accepted to use GPS, start searching for location

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy, this);
                    Log.d("locationmanager", "location result ok");
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                    this.finishAffinity();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The line Log.d("locationmanager", "location result ok"); is executed, but the above line does not seem to execute.

Finally here is my listener:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Log.d("changed location", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + " " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
}
```

Comment: make a location request in onConnected() function.

Comment: I am already doing that, but if the location isn't available on startup, the location in onConnected will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Location Listener class:

```
/**
 * Getting Navigation Updates.
 * <p>
 * Demonstrates how to use the Fused Navigation Provider API to get updates about a device's
 * location. The Fused Navigation Provider is part of the Google Play services location APIs.
 * <p>
 *
 *  Author Mayank
 */
public class GPSLocationListener implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "location-updates-sample";

    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    /**
     * The fastest rate for active location updates. Exact. Updates will never be more frequent
     * than this value.
     */
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    /**
     * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
     */
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;

    private Activity mActivity;


    public GPSLocationListener(Activity activity) {

        this.mActivity = activity;

        // Kick off the process of building a GoogleApiClient and requesting the LocationServices API.
        buildGoogleApiClient();

    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the
     * LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the location request. Android has two location request settings:
     * {@code ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} and {@code ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}. These settings control
     * the accuracy of the current location. This sample uses ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, as defined in
     * the AndroidManifest.xml.
     * <p/>
     * When the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION setting is specified, combined with a fast update
     * interval (5 seconds), the Fused Navigation Provider API returns location updates that are
     * accurate to within a few feet.
     * <p/>
     * These settings are appropriate for mapping applications that show real-time location
     * updates.
     */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
        // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
        // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
        // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
        // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    /**
     * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    /**
     * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    public void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
        // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
        // location updates if the user has requested them.

    }

    public void onStop() {

        // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");

        // If the initial location was never previously requested, we use
        // FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() to get it. If it was previously requested, we store
        // its value in the Bundle and check for it in onCreate().
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            locationReceived();
        }

        // start location updates.
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    /**
     * Callback that fires when the location changes.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(){
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }

}
```

In your Activity:

```
    //provides gps location updates
        private GPSLocationListener gpsLocationListener;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //call to location listener to start location updates when activity gets started
        if (gpsLocationListener != null) {
            gpsLocationListener.onStart();
        }

        }
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            //call to stop location updates when activity gets stopped
            if (gpsLocationListener != null) {
                gpsLocationListener.onStop();
            }

        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //call to initialize gpsLocationLister instance
        gpsLocationListener = new GPSLocationListener((MainActivity) mainView);

    }
```

Hope this helps you.